# Cannot fade in image when sidebar shows

Tags: javascript, html, css

First of all, I'm a complete beginner at coding so I'm still learning.

So I set me the task of making a website with a sidebar that opens and closes basically my own Resume page.

The thing is that I want an image to fade in when u open the sidebar and fade out when u close it, but I cannot find a solution on this and haven't had any luck :(

I'm using W3 schools sidebar.

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
};

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0px";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0px";
};
```

```css
.body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  animation: bgcolor infinite 50s;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  transition: background-color .5s;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 4em;
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  color: black;
}

.BackColorChange {
  animation: colorchange 25s;
  animation-duration: 25s;
  -webkit-animation: colorchange 25s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 10s;
  -moz-animation-duration: 10s;
  -o-animation-duration: 10s;
  -ms-animation-duration: 10s;
  animation-duration: 10s;
  -webkit-animation-name: bgswap;
  -moz-animation-name: bgswap;
  -o-animation-name: bgswap;
  -ms-animation-name: bgswap;
  animation-name: bgswap;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -ms-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -o-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -ms-animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@keyframes colorchange {
  0% {
    background: rgb(255, 252, 252);
  }
  15% {
    background: rgb(224, 214, 204);
  }
  30% {
    background: rgb(209, 195, 182);
  }
  60% {
    background: rgb(209, 195, 182);
  }
  75% {
    background: rgba(224, 214, 204, 0.4);
  }
  100% {
    background: rgba(255, 252, 252, 1);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes colorchange {
  0% {
    background: rgb(255, 252, 252);
  }
  15% {
    background: rgb(224, 214, 204);
  }
  30% {
    background: rgb(209, 195, 182);
  }
  60% {
    background: rgb(209, 195, 182);
  }
  75% {
    background: rgba(224, 214, 204, 0.4);
  }
  100% {
    background: rgba(255, 252, 252, 1);
  }
}

@keyframes bgswap {}

100% {
  background-image: url("http://getwallpapers.com/wallpaper/full/2/1/b/431542.jpg");
}

@-webkit-keyframes bgswap {
  100% {
    background-image: url("http://getwallpapers.com/wallpaper/full/2/1/b/431542.jpg");
  }
}


/*.backgroundImage {
     background-image: url("http://getwallpapers.com/wallpaper/full/2/1/b/431542.jpg");
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-position: center;
     background-size: cover;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
    }*/

.icons {
  line-height: 120px;
  padding: 20px 50px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

i {
  margin-left: 120px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.iconsSidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgb(38, 38, 38);
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 60px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.iconsSidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: rgb(204, 204, 204);
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.iconsSidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

#main {
  transition: margin-left .5s;
  padding: 20px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .iconsSidenav {
    padding-top: 15px;
  }
  .iconsSidenav a {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}
```

```html
<html class="BackColorChange">
<!--Header and all that stuff-->

<body class="backgroundImage">
  <h1> ! </h1>
  <div id="mySidenav" class="iconsSidenav">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">×</a>
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Specalities</a>
    <a href="#">Work</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
    <!--<i class="fas fa-bars" class="icons"></i>-->
  </div>
  <div id="main">
    <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer;" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will make the image appear/disappear when you click the button.

```
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
    document.getElementById("image").style.display = "block";
};

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0px";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0px";
    document.getElementById("image").style.display = "none";
};
```

---

This will make the image slide in and out. First, add this to the image's css:

```
transition: height 1s, width 1s, padding 1s, visibility 1s, opacity 0.5s ease-out;
```

This makes it visible, just replace the 50px  with the correct values for your page.

```
image.style.visibility = 'visible';
//hint.style.opacity = '1';
image.style.height = height + '50px';
image.style.width = width + '50px';
image.style.padding = '50px';
```

This makes it hidden

```
image.style.visibility = 'hidden';
//hint.style.opacity = '0';
image.style.height = '0';
image.style.width = '0';
image.style.padding = '0';
```

---

The code for changing an element's visibility in javascript is this:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('[insert element ID]');
elem.style.display = 'none'; //This hides the element
elem.style.display = 'block'; //This brings it back
```

The value in '' can be any css property that works with display:

If you have jQuery, this is even simpler, because you can just use

```
$(elem).hide();
$(elem).show();
```

If setting the display property isn't your preferred way to change it, you can also use visibility:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('[insert element ID]');
elem.style.visibility = 'hidden'; //This hides the element
elem.style.visibility = 'visible'; //This brings it back
```

The difference is that using `visibility:hidden;` tends to keep the place on screen reserved, whereas `display:none;` completely removes the element from the page (barring some annoying interactions with things like flexbox)

Comment: Thanks. Help a lot.

Comment: Happy to help. If my answer solved your problem, consider marking it as such so that people with a similar problem in the future can see that the question has an approved answer.